# How can I add ellipses (...) for longer text in an AgGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, ag-grid

I have below ag grid field where I want to add ellipses - (...) for characters greater than 100.

I tried below looking at few material over internet , but its not working -

```
{
  field : 'Latest Comments',
  headerName :  'Latest Comments',
  width : 250,
  cellStyle : { 'text-overflow':'ellipsis','white-space':'nowrap'}
}
```

Comment: It's `ellipsis`, not `ellipses`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: ellipsis should be added automatically, see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-4ldmsq?file=index.js) example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also set:

```css
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

So:

```js
{
    field : 'LatestComments',
    headerName :  'Latest Comments',
    maxWidth : 250,
    minWidth : 250,
    cellStyle : { 'text-overflow':'ellipsis','white-space':'nowrap', 'overflow': 'hidden', 'padding': 0 }
}
```

Comment: I would also add `display: block` for the cell

Answer (score 4):

- Ag-grid **by default** adds ellipses to long test
- but even if its not applying then try to add to cell

```css
{
  display: block;
}
```